# widget not displayed

Tags: widgets

the command

```
 echo '<pre>';print_r(wp_get_sidebars_widgets())  ;
```

returns

```
    [sidebar-page] => Array
    (
        [0] => execphp-5
        [1] => simple-section-nav-3
        [2] => execphp-4
        [3] => wp-forecast-3
        [4] => wp-forecast-4
        [5] => execphp-6
    )
```

but the sidebar page is not displayed 
instead the default bar is displayed.
why?

Comment: you want to display sidebar in a page or want to display `sidebar.php` page.

Comment: i want to display this sidebar in the page

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) function to display a sidebar in a page.

```
dynamic_sidebar('Name or ID of dynamic sidebar.')
```